# Jmeter (jmx) - How to run requests sequentially where first request response is dependent on the second request

Tags: jmeter, test-design, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm using `jmeter` for load testing so I'm a little bit stuck at this situation. Below is the scenario.

There are two `HTTPS` (target1 and target2) requests, which needed to be generated sequentially in `jmeter`.

ID value from response to `target1` request is needed in `target2`. Said ID is valid only once.

**What I tried was:**

Take the ID from the first request each time individually and send it in the `target2` request by increasing the `Threads` only not the loop count, because ID won't work for the 2nd time.

Is there any other way we can do `perf` test for this, because I need to test at least `5K-7.5K` users.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter always executes requests in sequential order. Retrieve the ID in first request by using Regular Expression Extractor and try to print in second request by using Beanshell PostProcessor.

Answer (score 2):

Put the requests in Critical Section Controller (under Logic Controller) according to your desired order.

Comment: This might be technically correct, but it still leaves the OP with the real problem: automatically retrieving the required ID parameter from the first response and inserting it into the second request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and adding [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor).

The script will look like this:
`vars.put("response", prev.getResponseDataAsString());`

but response that you get might be quite a lot. Since you only need the ID, then try adding `Regular Expression Extractor` too.

Then the "response" variable can be access as `${response}` and you can pass it on your targeted https2.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with increasing the number of loops? If you hit the `target1` second time it will produce the new ID, won't it? So the previous [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding the previous ID will be overwritten with the new ID so you will be able to hit the `target2` normally.

It also shouldn't be a problem to simulate 5-7k of virtual users from a mid-range modern laptop, just make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), if one machine is not enough you can always go for [running JMeter in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)